# Advance Custom Field to display specific content to logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress to show different clients information and I am new to ACF and I want to display contents as per a logged in customer. Different user have different data to be shown as a post. I have created fields to display for the user but I am not able to show the content as per a logged in user can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display for the user, you need to reference their username.

Use `get_current_user_id()` to capture the logged in user's ID and assign it as a variable:

```
<?php $userid = get_current_user_id();?>
```

Then you can pass the data just like any normal ACF field:

```
<?php the_field('field_name', $userid);?>
```

You can wrap both statements around a conditional `if` statement (such as `is_user_logged_in()`).